# How to call a class outside of the file

Tags: python, class

I am an APCS student so my primary language is Java but am currently writing a program that requires python which I know somewhat. I assume there is a way to call classes / methods outside the file in which they were created like in Java because they are both OO, but was wondering how I would go about doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example of what you have. As it stands, your question is extremely broad, and most likely covered by any basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you go about packaging your code (IE: you may end up using a python package or simply a module) you will likely use the import statement in a very similar way as you do java. Some Examples:

```
import my_module

my_object = my_module.MyClass()
```

or

```
from my_module import MyClass

my_object = MyClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the import statement, where you either import the whole file or just the required class.

For example, my directory has file1.py and file2.py. 
file2.py has a class named "A", which has the method print_hi().

So, in file1.py I do this:

```
from file2 import A

A.print_hi()
```

And I get the expected output.

Or, I could do this:

```
import file2

file2.A.print_hi()
```

which gives me the same output.But, you can't just import a method from a class which is present in another file --- you either import the file or the required class.

Thus, doing things like:
`from file2.A import print_hi`
or
`from file2 import A.print_hi`
won't work.